# How can we find the crossing point of two lines with a prescribed angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

In the 3D space, we have two given points of $P$ and $Q$.

Line $A$ passes through the point $P$ and whose angle with the x-axis is $\theta$ and with the z-axis $\phi$.

Line $B$ passes through the point $Q$ and has an angle of $\alpha$ with the line $A$.

How can we find the crossing point of the lines $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the given point $P$ and the properties of line $\theta$ and $\phi$, any point on the line can be written as

$$\vec{p_A} = \vec{P} + r \vec{l} $$

Here, $\vec{l} = \cos\theta \vec{i} + \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta - \cos^2\phi}\vec{j} + \cos\phi \vec{k}$

Now, you need to find $r$ such that

$$\frac{(\vec{p_A} - \vec{Q}).(\vec{l})}{||\vec{p_A} - \vec{Q}||} = \cos \alpha$$